# Finding an essential submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and let $M$ be a unitary faithful $R$-module. Assume the annihilator $A$ of $r\in R$ is essential in $R$ (as an $R$-module). I search for an essential submodule $N$ of $M$ such that $rN=0$.

I  tried first $N=AM$. It is clear that $rN=0$. Now, if $0≠m\in M$ we must find a $0≠t\in R$ with $0≠tm\in N$. I guessed then $t$ as a nonzero  element of $A$ (because $A≠0$ as it is essential in $R$) so that $tm\in N$. But, how could I be sure that it is not zero?

I don't know whether this strategy works. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where the submodule cannot be found (i.e., what
you are trying to prove is not true).

Let $R$ be the $\mathbb Q$-algebra with the presentation

$$
\langle x, y_1, y_2, \ldots\;|\;x^{i+1}y_i=0, i=1, 2, \ldots\rangle.
$$

Let $P$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by $\{y_i\;|\;i=1, 2, \ldots\}$.
$R/P\cong \mathbb Q[x]$, so $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ that does
not contain $x$. Therefore multiplication by $x$ on $R/P$ is an injective
function.

The annihilator of $x$ in $R$ contains the ideal
generated by $\{x^iy_i\;|\;i=1, 2, \ldots\}$, which is essential in $R$,
so $x$ belongs to the singular ideal of $R$.

Let $M = R\oplus R/P$. $M$ is a faithful module, because $R$ is a summand.
The annihilator $A$ of $x$ in $R$ is essential, as noted in the previous
paragraph. The annihilator
of $x$ in $M$ is $A\oplus \{0\}$, which is not essential, since it
is disjoint from $\{0\}\oplus R/P$. Thus there
can be no essential submodule $N\leq M$ that is annihilated by $x$.